# Cookie Law, does the user need to opt in, or is a link to cookie information enough

Tags: cookies

Struggling to find information on this...

Do you have to have e.g a pop up / information bar that says the cookie message and then has a opt in button. Or can you simply have a link in a footer that says cookie and data information etc.

Some people only do the later and if thats allowed it makes no sense to do anything else...

Answer (score 0):

Implied consent is absolutely fine, unless you're dealing with sensitive data, which means you just have to display information regarding your cookie use but the user doesn't have to actually click on anything to accept it before they can carry on.  The UK information commissioners office has some really good information: https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-pecr/cookies.  I'm not sure where you're based but the law is Europe wide so the advice would be the same regardless.

The [UK government site](https://www.gov.uk/) uses implied consent so if they're doing it you can assume you'll be ok.

As for those sites with explicit consent, I remember when the ruling was first made and there was an assumption that explicit consent was required so it is likely just sites which implemented the rules very early.  To be honest, I can't remember visiting any site which required me to agree to cookie use before continuing, buttons are usually just there to get rid of the annoying messages.

Simply having a link in the footer is not sufficient in my opinion, as the [ICO says](https://ico.org.uk/media/for-organisations/documents/1545/cookies_guidance.pdf):

> This remains the case if information is provided to the user but only as part of a privacy notice that is hard to find, difficult to understand or rarely read

Comment: Okay, currently I would use the 'okay' button as a method of hiding the message too. What about the fact of having no message at all? Simply having a cookie link in footer enough?

Comment: I don't believe, and I could be wrong, that is sufficient.  I've updated my answer with a qoute from the ICO guidelines.